# QTP/UFT: Move to next Test

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I would like to understand if it is possible to jump between Tests in UFT/QTP (Test Automation Tool).

I know we can jump from one 'action' to another in the same test by calling the second 'action' in the current script/action. But...

It is possible to call another Test? Or call another action in another Test? 
And if it is, how can we achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a Test from another Test in QTP/UFT. When we say calling another Test, an action from existing Test should be called.

Check the `Call to Existing Action` option under `Design`.

Comment: +1 because you took the time to answer a question which is totally covered (and easily locateable) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any Test by using the below given line of code in QTP

```
LoadandRunAction "PATH OF YOUR TEST","Action1",oneIteration
```

In place of "Action1", you can call any other action which has the script that is to be executed.